# Understanding (proportional to) through an example.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, education

This question may be redundant and I apologize in advance but I am really having a hard time to digest the notion of **proportional to** in mathematics. Kindly, can someone simplify the idea of it and when we can say proportional to something.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Proportional relationships are described by [linear functions](http://www.emathematics.net/imagenes/proportional1.gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quantity is **proportional to** another if you can multiply that quantity with a number $a$ to get the other quantity. That means, both quantities have the same **ratio**.

For example. The number of human legs is proportional to the number of people, because every person has two legs. Thus, the ratio of people to legs is 1 : 2. There are twice as many legs as people. (I do not mean to discriminate people with leg amputations).

Answer (score 2):

We say that $y$ is proportional to $x$ if there is a constant $c$ for which $y=cx$. Intuitively, this means that

- if we double $x$, then we double $y$
- if we triple $x$, then we triple $y$
- if we halve $x$, then we halve $y$

... and indeed, in general, if we scale $x$ **multiplicatively** by a certain amount, then we scale $y$ **multiplicatively** by that same amount. The earliest examples of this that we tend to come across are in converting units:

- something's length in metres is proportional to its length in cm
- something's weight in kilograms is proportional to its weight in pounds (lbs)
- something's value in US dollars is proportional to its value in pounds sterling (£)

When we start talking more abstractly about proportionality, we should go back to this scaling concept - any 2 squares are proportional, for example, because doubling the length of all sides of a square leads you to another square. However, this is not true of all shapes - to get from a triangle with sidelengths $\{3,4,5\}$ to a triangle with sidelengths $\{5,12,13\}$, you'd necessarily have to scale one side more than one of the others.

One way of showing this is to note that the first triangle has two sides in the ratio $4:3$, and this ought to be preserved by **multiplicative** scalings - upon a scaling of scale factor $f$, the sides would become $\{3f,4f,5f\}$, and $4f:3f=4:3$ for all nonzero $f$. However, none of the pairs of sides in the second triangle are in this ratio.

Comment: Good explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two variables $x$ and $y$ are said to be proportional provided that: if you multiply $x$  by $2$, then $y$ will also be multiplied by $2$; if you multiply $x$ by $3$, then $y$ will also be multiplied by $3$; in general, if you multiply $x$ by any constant $k\neq 0$, then $y$ will also be multiplied by $k$. Mathematically, this is expressed by saying that there is a constant $k$ such that $y=kx$.

Examples:

- (MILK) Assume that the price is $\$3.00$ per $1$L. The *total price* **is** proportional to the *amount of liters*: if we buy $3$ liters, we will pay $\$9.00$; if we buy $6$ liters (which is $2$ times $3$), we will pay $\$18.00$ (which is $2$ times $9$); in general, if we buy $L$ liters, we will pay $3L$. So, there is a constant $k$ (which is $3$) such that *total price* $=k$ *amount of liters*.
- (TAXI) Assume that the fare is $\$3.00$ (initial charge) plus $50$ cents per 1/5 mile. The *taxi fare* **isn't** proportional to the *traveled distance*: if we travel $3$ mile, we will pay $\$10.50$ but if we travel $6$ miles (which is $2$ times $3$) we will pay $\$18.00$ (which is not $2$ times $10,50$).